# Excel-VBA to find and return fastest race time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

**Purpose:** Interrogate race data and return fastest crew time for each class.

**Previous Research:** Have scoured multiple forums and have not been able to find anything relevant.

**Explanation:** I am trying to create a Macro which can read in the data set and then look at the category column, find the fastest time for that category and then return it to a specified cell.

**Example (with reference to image):**

This is how it would be done manually

Find the fastest 4x- in table;

- Search column C for 4x- (Ignoring the text in front (eg IM2. , W.J18A. etc))
- Search Column I for fastest time
- Return fastest time to cell P8

Any help will be most appreciated!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fZrE.png]]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do this.

But you'll need one more column (can be hidden). For example, let `N` column to be the one with additional info. It will consist of 3 last letters from `C` column (since we are interested in `4x-` at the end). So, in `N` column you need to paste such formula: `=right(C3, 3)` (it would be for `N3` cell, but you get the idea). Having this, in `P8` you need to enter formula:

```
=MAX(IF(N:N=O8, I:I))
```

Which means, take maximum only for those, that match value in `O8`, which is `4x-`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following User-defined Function (just put the code in a standard formula). To use it in your sheet, enter the formula - lets say - in P6: `=Fastest_from_cat($C$4:$I$100,O6)`

```
Public Function Fastest_from_cat(rng As Range, cat As String) As Double
Dim I As Long, col As Long
Dim Arr, tim As Double
tim = 999
Arr = rng.Value2
col = UBound(Arr, 2)
    For I = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        If Right(Arr(I, 1), Len(cat)) = cat And IsNumeric(Arr(I, col)) Then _
            If Arr(I, col) < tim Then tim = Arr(I, col)
    Next I
Fastest_from_cat = tim
End Function
```